# javascript - switch not working

Tags: javascript, string, switch-statement

```
function FM_log(level, text) {

    // caso não seja log total escolhe o que loga
    var log = false;
    switch (level) {
        case "addtoprio()":log = true;
        case "alternaTropas()":log = false;
        case "sendtroops()":log = false;
        defalt: log = false;
    }

    if ((logTotal == false) && (log == true))
        GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);
    else if (logTotal == true)
        GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);    
}
```

how to do that switch is a way it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`break` statements for your switch, and proper spelling of "default" should help you on your way :)

```
function FM_log(level, text) 
{
   // caso não seja log total escolhe o que loga
   var log = false;
   switch (level) 
   {
      case "addtoprio()":
         log = true;
         break;
      case "alternaTropas()":
         log = false;
         break;
      case "sendtroops()":
         log = false;
         break;
      default: 
         log = false;
         break;
   }

   if ((logTotal == false) && (log == true))
      GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);
   else if (logTotal == true)
      GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Two Problems:**

- You are missing the `break` keyword after each `case` clause.
- Your spelling for the `default` was wrong.

.

```
   switch (level) {
        case "addtoprio()":log = true; break;
        case "alternaTropas()":log = false; break;
        case "sendtroops()":log = false; break;
        default: log = false; break;
    }
```

[More On Switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: same here: default not defalt.

Answer (score 2):

You must add break instruction after each case, and use default not defalt.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
function FM_log(level, text) {

    // caso não seja log total escolhe o que loga
    var log = false;
    switch (level) {
        case "addtoprio()":log = true; break;
        case "alternaTropas()":log = false; break;
        case "sendtroops()":log = false; break;
        defalt: log = false; break;
    }

    if ((logTotal == false) && (log == true))
        GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);
    else if (logTotal == true)
        GM_log(horaAtual() + " - "+level+", "+text);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where adding a break statement did not correct the problem.  I finally corrected the problem by making sure I passed a string type into the switch statement.  You can do this in your case by `var newStr = level + "";`.  The `+ ""` will ensure it's a string type.  Then pass `newStr` into your switch statement.